# Icon to depict quality?

Tags: gui-design, icons

I'm looking for an icon to represent "high quality."

I'm thinking of using a diamond shape. Is there any reason to think that a diamond does not represent high quality?

Comment: Is this icon to be put next to a 'low quality' icon as a pair, or is this icon to represent high quality on its own?

Comment: To represent on it's own

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A diamond icon might be misleading because it's not commonly used to indicate an objects quality.

To represent "high quality" using only the Font Awesome icon pack I would stick to the traditional check-marks, stars, thumbs-up and certificate icons.

[image: Font Awesome quality icons]

Answer (score 3):

It would help to know what exactly we a assigning a quality to here, but if its something such as internet quality or video quality you could use "signal bars"
[image]

Alone they don't provide much meaning but the idea is relative to others you can see the difference in quality.

This same concept can be used with other measurable items such as movie or books quality with stars:
[image]

Keep in mind this only works if you need to denote high quality items relative to low quality items. If you need an icon that stands alone as a representation of high quality I would say a single gold star implies more than a diamond.